# why background not appearing correctly

Tags: css

I have background style of #bg_inner as background:transparent url(../images/bg_inner.jpg) repeat-x scroll center top;. But only part of it appears. Any idea why?

Test link:
http://www.aslanyurek.com/inner.asp?Section=myaccount&SubSection=signin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `#bg_inner` is only the size of `#header`, which is 35 pixels. There's nothing to display the background in once `#bg_inner`'s block is drawn. See, you have the inner form set to float left, which brings it outside of `#bg_inner`. Basically, you've shortened your own header section.

You should just define your background properties on the `body` element itself and remove `#bg_inner` entirely. Either that or remove the `float:left;` property from the form element.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My firebug is not working for some reason. Couldnt check it myself.